# Deleting pairwise duplicates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

On SQL Server, the following sql counts the number of identical rows that I have per pairwise OrgID and FeatureID:

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT COUNT(1) AS Total, OrgID, FeatureID
FROM            Organisation.Tag AS t
GROUP BY OrgID, FeatureID
HAVING        (COUNT(1) > 1)
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

However, I am not interested in the duplicates. What is the SQL to delete the duplicates?

The table itself contains the following fields:

```
[TagID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[LastModified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[OrgID] [int] NULL,
[FeatureID] [int] NOT NULL
```

Comment: Are they identical rows? Does your table have a primary/unique key column?

Comment: Yes, there are identical rows but not all rows are identical, as they differ by orgid and featureid. There is a uniquekey TagID; orgid and featureid are foreign keys.

Comment: Did the duplicates get in there by error?  Would (OrgID, FeatureID) be a candidate LOGICAL key to the relation?  what application manages the inserts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by ordid, featureid
                                     order by lastmodified desc) as seqnum
      from organization.tag
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: I get: The ranking function "row_number" must have an ORDER BY clause - I even changed ordid to orgid

Comment: Just add `Order by` clause like: `(partition by ordid, featureid ORDER BY LastModified)`

Comment: Ok, the following did it: WITH cte
AS (SELECT
  TagID,
  FeatureID,
  OrgID,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY featureid, orgid ORDER BY LastModified) AS seqnum
FROM Organisation.Tag)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE seqnum > 1

Comment: Oops.   That was originally a `count(*) over` and I left out the `order by` when I changed the logic.